# How do I find out what filesystem my partitions are using?

Tags: filesystem, partitioning

Is there a way to find out what file system my partitions are using?

Comment: Try `sudo blkid -o list > ~/myFileSytems` on a terminal to found out. Then open the file `myFileSystems` with a text editor (the file should be in your home folder). But I consider that is not your main issue, you might want to provide more info in your question.

Comment: I'm curious why on earth a filesystem would affect the persistence of your settings.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34623/how-to-tell-what-type-of-filesystem-youre-on

Comment: Q&A I just added, which asks the opposite question: [How do I find out which partitions my filesystems (and mount points) are on, and how full they are?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/733886/114401)

Answer (score 99):

There are a number of ways to do this from the command line (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>):

The command `df -T` will print your filesystem types, as follows:

```
~$ df -T
Filesystem     Type      1K-blocks       Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1      ext4      190230236  102672812  77894244  57% /
udev           devtmpfs    1021128         12   1021116   1% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs        412884        816    412068   1% /run
none           tmpfs          5120          0      5120   0% /run/lock
none           tmpfs       1032208       2584   1029624   1% /run/shm
cgroup         tmpfs       1032208          0   1032208   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sdb1      fuseblk  1953480700 1141530424 811950276  59% /home/user/storage
```

[This article](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/04/identify-file-system-type/) sums up several other methods of obtaining this information.

Here are a couple of other examples that I use occasionally:

```
~$ mount | grep "^/dev"
/dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/sdb1 on /home/user/storage type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,blksize=4096)

~$ sudo file -sL /dev/sda1
/dev/sda1: Linux rev 1.0 ext4 filesystem data, UUID=b53ecdf7-5247-4d65-91a6-be9264c84dea (extents) (large files) (huge files)
```

Comment: Note that with $ df -T filesystem called fuseblk means NTFS but $ sudo lsblk -f actually shows ntfs.

Comment: The last one (`sudo file -sL /dev/sda1`) is exactly what I needed - you should put that one first.

Answer (score 61):

You can also use the `lsblk` command like this:

```
$ sudo lsblk -f

NAME        FSTYPE LABEL      MOUNTPOINT
sda                           
├─sda1      ntfs   OS         
├─sda2      ntfs   Data       
├─sda3                        
├─sda5      ext4              /
└─sda6      swap              [SWAP]
```

Comment: It shows blank for several partitions.  How do I see the File System byte for those?

Comment: `sudo` does not seem to be needed

Comment: sudo is not needed when sysfs and udev are available.  -f doesn't seem to be needed either as fstype is printed by default.

Answer (score 32):

**A simple and good command**

```
sudo blkid
```

**It will list something like this:**

```
/dev/sda1: LABEL="Windows" UUID="FA50DCB150DC763B" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda5: LABEL="40GBTWO" UUID="00A0CE7EA0CE7A24" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda6: UUID="7550252c-3da7-4cd9-8da3-71e9ba38e74a" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda7: UUID="088fd084-a011-4896-aa93-c0caaad60620" TYPE="swap"
```

Where `/dev/sda1` is the partition, `LABEL` is the given name to the partition, `UUID` is the Unique ID of the partiton which is quite useful to mount the hardisk using `/etc/fstab`, and `TYPE` is the file system.

I often use this command to get almost all the information about my hard drive and removal drive. Hope you too like it. :)

Comment: +1, good solution. Note that `blkid` does not need to be run as root. Also, you can give a specific partition as an argument to `blkid` and get info for just that partition, a la `blkid /dev/sda1`.

Comment: @AJMansfield You will need root privileges to get meaningful output.

Answer (score 14):

In the Dash type *Disk* and open the disk utility application, which is called either *Disk Utility* in Ubuntu 12.04 and Ubuntu 12.10, or *Disks* in Ubuntu 13.04 and later.

The screenshot shows the Disks window with the 500 GB Hard Disk selected to display information about that disk. In the center pane in the **Volumes** section you can see that the second partition on that hard disk has been selected to display information about that partition. In the **Volumes** section you can also see the description *Contents: **Ext4*** which means that the partition is formatted as Ext4 which is the default Ubuntu filesystem format.

[image]
<sup>**Disks in Ubuntu 18.04**</sup>

Comment: +0 Nice that there is a GUI way of doing this, but anyone who really cares what filesystem they are using (or even knows what a "filesystem" is) is probably looking for a command line solution.

Comment: @AJMansfield +0? LOL. BTW, I care, and I strongly prefer GUI.

Comment: @AJMansfield while CLI is more robust and will work in rescue environment (`initramfs`), when you have very complex partitioning situation, with multiple volume groups, raid, etc. a graphical tool makes it easier to read

Answer (score 2):

Try this in terminal:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

Simply copy & paste the command into your terminal.

If I understand you correctly, this should show your drives.

Comment: `fdisk -l` doesn't show the filesystem

Comment: My fdisk (2.20.1 on Ubuntu 14.04) shows the FS, albeit not very specifically.  "Linux" instead of ext4, etc.

Comment: @MatthewRead that is based on a numerical code which is usually, but not always, correct - almost everything ignores the code, so it doesn't have to be correct, and it might not be.

Comment: +1 This is the only answer that worked for me -- nothing else would tell me if my partitions were 82, 83, or 8e.

Comment: Please note that while fdisk will tell you what (family) of file systems is *supposed* to be on a given partition, it does not check if an actual filesystem is present on any given partition. Also, for Linux that information is not even advisory, it will mount an FS irrespective of partition Id (type).